# How to get just the character inserted in textinput?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to know how can I get only the character that wad inserted in the textinput and not the entire text, I mean, if I type a, in the console should print a, not the entire text with the a, to do that:

```
<TextInput
  Onchangetext = {text => this.setstate({title:text}), () => console.log (this.state.title)}
>
```

If my title was hi, when I type a, in the console print hia, i just want it to print a, how can I do this?

Comment: What is the user pastes some text? Then it's not only the inserted character, but many characters. What if the user deletes a character? What if the user deletes more than one characters?

Comment: mmmm, thats right, but i was asking it because I want to know if the user inserts a blank space, in my case I want to know if it was inserted a ```&nbsp;```

Comment: `onkeypress` ... ?

Comment: You don't need to look for the last input. You can still do that by looking at the whole string. If the string previously didn't contain a space, and now does, it means that the user has inserted one or more spaces.

Comment: `onkeypress` won't catch inserting a space (or any character or set or characters for that matter) by doing CTRL + V, or right clicking and using “Paste” from the context menu. Therefore, it's not reliable.

Comment: Whole concept seems to want to limit "normal" ui controls @LazarLjubenović

Comment: onkeypress is not going to use &nbsp; .... Not following either how onkeypress ignores a keyboard spacebar either

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fnSingleValue(e)
{
  alert((e).value.slice(-1));
  console.log((e).value.slice(-1));
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="fnSingleValue(this)"/>
```

Comment: Upvoter never tested if say "eu" place cursor at anywhere other than end, then typed a key. This answer does not sufficiently answer "last typed character" as posed by OP. .... but maybe im mistaken

Comment: This is not an answer, this is piece of code. Please explain what you did and how it solved the problem, so the OP and future readers can learn something from it.

Comment: Also it's broken; it's fairly easy to type two or more letters in succession. Not to talk about deleting characters or adding them in the middle of the word. Also using left-right arrows brings up the alert without even changing the input.